# Given a collection of IPoints is there a quick way to get the extent that contains them?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I have a bunch of IPoints.  I need an extent which contains all of them.  Is there a quick way to do it?   I had the idea of converting them to screen coordinates and then figuring it out manually but that seems like the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd leverage [IEnvelope.Union](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Union_Method/002m00000197000000/).  All IGeometry objects have an envelope, including points.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
envelope e = null
Foreach point
   if e == null then
      e = point.Envelope
   else
      e.Union(point.Envelope)
   end if
next point
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually do it Kirk's way, but you could add them to a geometry bag and get the extent:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001s8000000

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=114648